# Quicksort didn't do anything, now stuck in forever loop

Tags: c++, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the in-place version of quicksort. This is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

size_t partition(vector<int>& v, size_t l, size_t r, size_t p)
{
    size_t pivot = v[p];
    swap(v[p], v[r]);
    size_t store = l;

    for (size_t i = l; l < (r-1); i++) {
        if (v[i] <= pivot) {
            swap(v[i], v[store]);
            store++;
        }
    }
    swap(v[store], v[r]);

    return store;
}

void quickSort(vector<int>& v, size_t l, size_t r)
{
    //If two or more elements
    if(l<r)
    {
        size_t pI = l;
        size_t nP = partition(v, l, r, pI);

        quickSort(v, (nP+1), r);
        quickSort(v, l, (nP-1));
    }
}
```

For reference, I'm using the pseudocode for the [in-place version on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#In-place_version).

The problems I'm having is that I at first accidentily called the function with the middle of the list as the leftmost arguemtn. the program ran error free and ouputted the new list, totally unchanged and unsorted (no errors at all). I found my error, and now I call the function like this:

```
quickSort(v, 0, (v.size()-1));
```

And Xcode warns me that I'm getting stuck in a forever loop at

```
if (v[i] <= pivot)
```

It's at that exact line, as if the comparison triggers something. I would be delighted if you could help me!

Comment: Hi. Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're comparing `l < r - 1` but incrementing `i` on every iteration of the for loop. Hence, infinite loop. Change `for (size_t i = l; l < (r-1); i++) {` to `for (size_t i = l; i < (r-1); i++) {`.

Comment: Yes and also it should be `< r` according to referenced pseudo code.